# How to avoid variable substitution in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

When I try to execute this statement in Oracle SQL Developer 2.1 a dialog box *"Enter Substitution Variable"* pops up asking for a replacement value for *TOBAGO*,

```
update t set country = 'Trinidad and Tobago' where country = 'trinidad & tobago';
```

How can I avoid this without resorting to `chr(38)` or `u'trinidad \0026 tobago'` which both obscure the purpose of the statement?

Comment: That's strange, when I attempted to run a query exactly like that in SQL developer 2.1 I did not get the replacement variable window? (And my defines are most certainly set to on)

Answer (score 235, accepted):

Call this before the query:

```
set define off;
```

Alternatively, hacky:

```
update t set country = 'Trinidad and Tobago' where country = 'trinidad &' || ' tobago';
```

---

From [Tuning SQL*Plus](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch8.htm):

> SET DEFINE OFF disables the parsing of commands to replace
>   substitution variables with their values.

Comment: What (else) does `set define off;` do?

Comment: SET DEFINE OFF: `Invalid "set define" command`

Answer (score 16):

In SQL*Plus putting `SET DEFINE ?` at the top of the script will normally solve this. Might work for Oracle SQL Developer as well.

Comment: SET DEFINE ? does suppress the variable substitution behaviour in SQL Developer 2.1. As noted by Nick SET DEFINE OFF also works.

Comment: set define works but the DBA wont allow to use  it sometimes i dont know why

Comment: Doesn't work. `Invalid "set define" command`

Answer (score 1):

this will work as you asked without CHAR(38):

```
update t set country = 'Trinidad and Tobago' where country = 'trinidad & '|| 'tobago';

create table table99(col1 varchar(40));
insert into table99 values('Trinidad &' || '  Tobago');
insert into table99 values('Trinidad &' || '  Tobago');
insert into table99 values('Trinidad &' || '  Tobago');
insert into table99 values('Trinidad &' || '  Tobago');
SELECT * FROM table99;

update table99 set col1 = 'Trinidad and Tobago' where col1 = 'Trinidad &'||'  Tobago';
```

Comment: My question was how this could be done without using `chr(38)`.

Comment: @JanekBogucki take it it correct now without using CHAR(38)

Comment: i gave you a different answer  as you already have green ticked answer but you downvoted

Comment: Mate you cannot imagine what an agony you solved for me, sql developer does not accept set define off when you run a script. This the solution for me

Answer (score 1):

If you use liquibase to run sql file, it will not give error. But for sql developer use this `set define off;` before  ur sql sode

Answer (score -3):

set scan off;
Above command also works.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you earn sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post. If you have a related but different question, ask a new question referencing this one if it will help provide context.