# select from oracle table where field like P & L

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I am trying to select from a table where a field name like P & L but I am getting prompted for Substitution variable. Is there a way to fire that query without the Substitution variable and get the same results?

My select Statement:

```
select * from student_master_table where STU_MIDDLE_NAME like '%P & L%';
```

SqlDeveloper Prompt:
[image]

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simpliest way is to break string in two strings:

```
select * from student_master_table where STU_MIDDLE_NAME like '%P &'||' L%';
```

Answer (score 0):

ou have to escape the 'L'

set DEFINE OFF;

select * from student_master_table where STU_MIDDLE_NAME like '%P & L%';

Comment: `ORA-01424: missing or illegal character following the escape character
01424. 00000 -  "missing or illegal character following the escape character"
*Cause:    The character following the escape character in LIKE pattern is
           missing or not one of the escape character, '%', or '_'.`

Comment: yes, you'are right, you need to set DEFINE OFF. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333994/how-to-avoid-variable-substitution-in-oracle-sql-developer-with-trinidad-toba