# invalid NEW or OLD specification Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm getting "invalid NEW or OLD specification" from this:

```
create or replace trigger subscription_length
after insert or update of date_start, date_end on subscriptions
for each row
when (DATEDIFF(month, new.date_start, new.date_end) > 60)
begin
    insert into tab_audit_subscriptions values(seq_audit_sub.nextval, sys_context('userenv', 
      'session_user'), sys_context('userenv', 'sessionid'), sys_context('userenv', 'host'), 
      sysdate, 0, 'SUBSCRIPTION_LENGTH');
end;
```

I then changed it to this after what I read online:

```
create or replace trigger subscription_length
after insert or update of date_start, date_end on subscriptions
for each row
when (DATEDIFF(month, :NEW.date_start, :NEW.date_end) > 60)
begin
    insert into tab_audit_subscriptions values(seq_audit_sub.nextval, sys_context('userenv', 
      'session_user'), sys_context('userenv', 'sessionid'), sys_context('userenv', 'host'), 
      sysdate, 0, 'SUBSCRIPTION_LENGTH');
end;
```

I get an "Enter binds" window and I just press apply, and I get this "invalid use of bind variable in trigger WHEN clause". It recommends using simple NEW/OLD, which don't work, as shown above..

What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Oracle has no `datediff()` function

Comment: So should it be something like when (new.date_end - new.date_start > 1825‬) ? I get invalid character for this one

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333994/how-to-avoid-variable-substitution-in-oracle-sql-developer-with-trinidad-toba

Comment: `date1 - date2` returns the number of days and it could be slightly different than what you expect, fortunately, there's [MONTHS_BETWEEN](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions114.htm#SQLRF00669) function there

Comment: Great @micklesh, it worked now. the trigger compiled and the audit table is populated. Thank you

Comment: glad it helped @Angelo

Comment: I suppose the error message is misleading here. It is trying to tell you that the `when` expression as a whole is invalid (you'd get the same error from `when (nosuchfunction(new.start_date) = 0)`), but the wording suggests it is about the `new` and `old` column references, which you actually had right the first time.