# How to avoid & popup when SQL query contain '&' letter?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am writing a migration script where I replaced html encoded values by original values like `&amp;` will get replaced by `&`. So my SQL query has `&` letter but when I execute this query it give me popup for every `&` to replace that character which is as shown below

[image]

After clicking on **OK** its giving anexpecetd result but actually this popup should not come for every *&*. What should have to do to avoid this popup?

Comment: A similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333994/how-to-avoid-variable-substitution-in-oracle-sql-developer-with-trinidad-toba

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the top of your script, add:

```
set define off;
```