# regexp_substr is skipping all the &X

Tags: regex, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

This is for Oracle, not MySql in case there might be a slight difference.

I am trying to get paths of this url

```
select regexp_substr(
'https://domain/l202108091338.csv.zip?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAQ6R%2F20210820%2Fca-central-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20210820T223109Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=bd3d40250afdc751c67c58302a2ca152c7&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host',
'[^=]+',
1,
2
) from dual;
```

the above command outputs

```
AWS4-HMAC-SHA256-Amz-Credential
```

but the actually value is

```
AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential
```

How can I make the output includes `&X` too?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions and help.

Comment: Cannot replicate the problem [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=785bc13f6792004b1ce8a92c2dd3d232).

Comment: @MT0 weird, if you run it in Oracle SQL Developer or in ODI, it will be empty :(

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/2333994/1509264 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/34332639/1509264 If using `SET DEFINE OFF` fixes the issue then it is going to be a duplicate.

Comment: @MT0 but I wonder would this affect the whole db and not a good practice to do?

Comment: `set define off` turns the `define` setting off for the current `SQL*Plus` session.  It has no impact on other sessions or the database as a whole.  It's a client-only setting.

Comment: No, SQL/Plus and SQL Developer both would be treating `&X` as a substitution variable and substituting it with a replacement on the **client** side so that the server never sees the `&X` and only sees the replacement (which is presumably an empty string). Using `SET DEFINE OFF` will only affect your client and not the database.

Comment: @JustinCave and MT0

Thanks a lot for clarifying ^_^